# Unity - EasyAR 3.1.0 webcam black screen since updating Unity to 2021.1.18f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, webcam-capture, easyar

EasyAR 3.1.0 worked properly in older versions of Unity. The webcam loaded as expected, but since I've updated to Unity 2021.1.18f1, the webcam only shows a black screen. I tested it with the samples provided here: https://www.easyar.com/view/downloadHistory.html with the same result: the webcam texture stays black.
To make sure, that it's not a problem with my webcam, I tried this example here: https://community.theta360.guide/t/simplest-webcam-test-in-unity/516/3 and was able to load the webcam texture properly.

I also tried using another webcam with EasyAR, but the EasyAR webcam texture stays black.

I have no idea what the problem is, since it worked before without any problems. Has anything changed between Unity 2020.2 and 2021.1 in terms of loading the webcam?

**Here is the CameraImageRenderer.cs script:**

```cs
//================================================================================================================================
//
//  Copyright (c) 2015-2019 VisionStar Information Technology (Shanghai) Co., Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
//  EasyAR is the registered trademark or trademark of VisionStar Information Technology (Shanghai) Co., Ltd in China
//  and other countries for the augmented reality technology developed by VisionStar Information Technology (Shanghai) Co., Ltd.
//
//================================================================================================================================

using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

namespace easyar
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(RenderCameraController))]
    public class CameraImageRenderer : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private RenderCameraController controller;
        private CommandBuffer commandBuffer;
        private CameraImageMaterial arMaterial;
        private Material material;
        private CameraParameters cameraParameters;
        private bool renderImageHFlip;
        private UserRequest request;

        public event Action<Material, Vector2> OnFrameRenderUpdate;
        private event Action<Camera, RenderTexture> TargetTextureChange;

        protected virtual void Awake()
        {
            controller = GetComponent<RenderCameraController>();
            arMaterial = new CameraImageMaterial();
        }

        protected virtual void OnEnable()
        {
            UpdateCommandBuffer(controller ? controller.TargetCamera : null, material);
        }

        protected virtual void OnDisable()
        {
            RemoveCommandBuffer(controller ? controller.TargetCamera : null);
        }

        protected virtual void OnDestroy()
        {
            arMaterial.Dispose();
            if (request != null) { request.Dispose(); }
            if (cameraParameters != null) { cameraParameters.Dispose(); }
        }

        public void RequestTargetTexture(Action<Camera, RenderTexture> targetTextureEventHandler)
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                request = new UserRequest();
            }
            TargetTextureChange += targetTextureEventHandler;
            RenderTexture texture;
            request.UpdateTexture(controller ? controller.TargetCamera : null, material, out texture);
            if (TargetTextureChange != null && texture)
            {
                TargetTextureChange(controller.TargetCamera, texture);
            }
        }

        public void DropTargetTexture(Action<Camera, RenderTexture> targetTextureEventHandler)
        {
            if (controller)
            {
                targetTextureEventHandler(controller.TargetCamera, null);
            }
            TargetTextureChange -= targetTextureEventHandler;
            if (TargetTextureChange == null && request != null)
            {
                request.RemoveCommandBuffer(controller ? controller.TargetCamera : null);
                request.Dispose();
                request = null;
            }
        }

        public void OnAssemble(ARSession session)
        {
            session.FrameChange += OnFrameChange;
            session.FrameUpdate += OnFrameUpdate;
        }

        public void SetHFilp(bool hFlip)
        {
            renderImageHFlip = hFlip;
        }

        private void OnFrameChange(OutputFrame outputFrame, Matrix4x4 displayCompensation)
        {
            if (outputFrame == null)
            {
                material = null;
                UpdateCommandBuffer(controller ? controller.TargetCamera : null, material);
                if (request != null)
                {
                    request.UpdateCommandBuffer(controller ? controller.TargetCamera : null, material);
                    RenderTexture texture;
                    if (TargetTextureChange != null && request.UpdateTexture(controller.TargetCamera, material, out texture))
                    {
                        TargetTextureChange(controller.TargetCamera, texture);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            if (!enabled && request == null && OnFrameRenderUpdate == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            using (var frame = outputFrame.inputFrame())
            {
                using (var image = frame.image())
                {
                    var materialUpdated = arMaterial.UpdateByImage(image);
                    if (material != materialUpdated)
                    {
                        material = materialUpdated;
                        UpdateCommandBuffer(controller ? controller.TargetCamera : null, material);
                        if (request != null) { request.UpdateCommandBuffer(controller ? controller.TargetCamera : null, material); }
                    }
                }
                if (cameraParameters != null)
                {
                    cameraParameters.Dispose();
                }
                cameraParameters = frame.cameraParameters();
            }
        }

        private void OnFrameUpdate(OutputFrame outputFrame)
        {
            if (!controller || (!enabled && request == null && OnFrameRenderUpdate == null))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (request != null)
            {
                RenderTexture texture;
                if (TargetTextureChange != null && request.UpdateTexture(controller.TargetCamera, material, out texture))
                {
                    TargetTextureChange(controller.TargetCamera, texture);
                }
            }

            if (!material)
            {
                return;
            }

            bool cameraFront = cameraParameters.cameraDeviceType() == CameraDeviceType.Front ? true : false;
            var imageProjection = cameraParameters.imageProjection(controller.TargetCamera.aspect, EasyARController.Instance.Display.Rotation, false, cameraFront? !renderImageHFlip : renderImageHFlip).ToUnityMatrix();
            if (renderImageHFlip)
            {
                var translateMatrix = Matrix4x4.identity;
                translateMatrix.m00 = -1;
                imageProjection = translateMatrix * imageProjection;
            }
            material.SetMatrix("_TextureRotation", imageProjection);
            if (OnFrameRenderUpdate != null)
            {
                OnFrameRenderUpdate(material, new Vector2(Screen.width * controller.TargetCamera.rect.width, Screen.height * controller.TargetCamera.rect.height));
            }
        }

        private void UpdateCommandBuffer(Camera cam, Material material)
        {
            RemoveCommandBuffer(cam);
            if (!cam || !material)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (enabled)
            {
                commandBuffer = new CommandBuffer();
                commandBuffer.Blit(null, BuiltinRenderTextureType.CameraTarget, material);
                cam.AddCommandBuffer(CameraEvent.BeforeForwardOpaque, commandBuffer);
            }
        }

        private void RemoveCommandBuffer(Camera cam)
        {
            if (commandBuffer != null)
            {
                if (cam)
                {
                    cam.RemoveCommandBuffer(CameraEvent.BeforeForwardOpaque, commandBuffer);
                }
                commandBuffer.Dispose();
                commandBuffer = null;
            }
        }

        private class UserRequest : IDisposable
        {
            private RenderTexture texture;
            private CommandBuffer commandBuffer;

            ~UserRequest()
            {
                if (commandBuffer != null) { commandBuffer.Dispose(); }
                if (texture) { Destroy(texture); }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (commandBuffer != null) { commandBuffer.Dispose(); }
                if (texture) { Destroy(texture); }
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }

            public bool UpdateTexture(Camera cam, Material material, out RenderTexture tex)
            {
                tex = texture;
                if (!cam || !material)
                {
                    if (texture)
                    {
                        Destroy(texture);
                        tex = texture = null;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                int w = (int)(Screen.width * cam.rect.width);
                int h = (int)(Screen.height * cam.rect.height);
                if (texture && (texture.width != w || texture.height != h))
                {
                    Destroy(texture);
                }

                if (texture)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    texture = new RenderTexture(w, h, 0);
                    UpdateCommandBuffer(cam, material);
                    tex = texture;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public void UpdateCommandBuffer(Camera cam, Material material)
            {
                RemoveCommandBuffer(cam);
                if (!cam || !material)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (texture)
                {
                    commandBuffer = new CommandBuffer();
                    commandBuffer.Blit(null, texture, material);
                    cam.AddCommandBuffer(CameraEvent.BeforeForwardOpaque, commandBuffer);
                }
            }

            public void RemoveCommandBuffer(Camera cam)
            {
                if (commandBuffer != null)
                {
                    if (cam)
                    {
                        cam.RemoveCommandBuffer(CameraEvent.BeforeForwardOpaque, commandBuffer);
                    }
                    commandBuffer.Dispose();
                    commandBuffer = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the VideoCameraDevice.cs script:**

```cs
//================================================================================================================================
//
//  Copyright (c) 2015-2019 VisionStar Information Technology (Shanghai) Co., Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
//  EasyAR is the registered trademark or trademark of VisionStar Information Technology (Shanghai) Co., Ltd in China
//  and other countries for the augmented reality technology developed by VisionStar Information Technology (Shanghai) Co., Ltd.
//
//================================================================================================================================

using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace easyar
{
    public class VideoCameraDevice : CameraSource
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// EasyAR Sense API. Accessible between DeviceCreated and DeviceClosed event if available.
        /// </summary>
        public CameraDevice Device { get; private set; }

        public CameraDeviceFocusMode FocusMode = CameraDeviceFocusMode.Continousauto;
        public Vector2 CameraSize = new Vector2(1280, 960);
        public CameraDeviceOpenMethod CameraOpenMethod = CameraDeviceOpenMethod.DeviceType;
        [HideInInspector, SerializeField]
        public CameraDeviceType CameraType = CameraDeviceType.Back;
        [HideInInspector, SerializeField]
        public int CameraIndex = 0;

        [HideInInspector, SerializeField]
        private CameraDevicePreference cameraPreference = CameraDevicePreference.PreferObjectSensing;
        private CameraParameters parameters = null;
        private bool willOpen;

        public event Action DeviceCreated;
        public event Action DeviceOpened;
        public event Action DeviceClosed;

        public enum CameraDeviceOpenMethod
        {
            DeviceType,
            DeviceIndex,
        }

        public override int BufferCapacity
        {
            get
            {
                if (Device != null)
                {
                    return Device.bufferCapacity();
                }
                return bufferCapacity;
            }
            set
            {
                bufferCapacity = value;
                if (Device != null)
                {
                    Device.setBufferCapacity(value);
                }
            }
        }

        public override bool HasSpatialInformation
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public CameraDevicePreference CameraPreference
        {
            get { return cameraPreference; }

            // Switch to prefered FocusMode when switch CameraPreference.
            // You can set other FocusMode after this, but the tracking results may differ.
            set
            {
                cameraPreference = value;
                switch (cameraPreference)
                {
                    case CameraDevicePreference.PreferObjectSensing:
                        FocusMode = CameraDeviceFocusMode.Continousauto;
                        break;
                    case CameraDevicePreference.PreferSurfaceTracking:
                        FocusMode = CameraDeviceFocusMode.Medium;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public CameraParameters Parameters
        {
            get
            {
                if (Device != null)
                {
                    return Device.cameraParameters();
                }
                return parameters;
            }
            set
            {
                parameters = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnEnable()
        {
            base.OnEnable();
            if (Device != null)
            {
                Device.start();
            }
        }

        protected override void Start()
        {
            if (!CameraDevice.isAvailable())
            {
                throw new UIPopupException(typeof(CameraDevice) + " not available");
            }

            base.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnDisable()
        {
            base.OnDisable();
            if (Device != null)
            {
                Device.stop();
            }
        }

        public override void Open()
        {
            willOpen = true;
            CameraDevice.requestPermissions(EasyARController.Scheduler, (Action<PermissionStatus, string>)((status, msg) =>
            {
                if (!willOpen)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    throw new UIPopupException("Camera permission not granted");
                }

                Close();
                Device = CameraDeviceSelector.createCameraDevice(CameraPreference);
                if (DeviceCreated != null)
                {
                    DeviceCreated();
                }

                bool openResult = false;
                switch (CameraOpenMethod)
                {
                    case CameraDeviceOpenMethod.DeviceType:
                        openResult = Device.openWithPreferredType(CameraType);
                        break;
                    case CameraDeviceOpenMethod.DeviceIndex:
                        openResult = Device.openWithIndex(CameraIndex);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                if (!openResult)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Camera open failed");
                    Device.Dispose();
                    Device = null;
                    return;
                }

                Device.setFocusMode(FocusMode);
                Device.setSize(new Vec2I((int)CameraSize.x, (int)CameraSize.y));
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    Device.setCameraParameters(parameters);
                }
                if (bufferCapacity != 0)
                {
                    Device.setBufferCapacity(bufferCapacity);
                }

                if (sink != null)
                    Device.inputFrameSource().connect(sink);

                if (DeviceOpened != null)
                {
                    DeviceOpened();
                }

                if (enabled)
                {
                    OnEnable();
                }
            }));
        }

        public override void Close()
        {
            willOpen = false;
            if (Device != null)
            {
                OnDisable();
                Device.close();
                Device.Dispose();
                if (DeviceClosed != null)
                {
                    DeviceClosed();
                }
                Device = null;
            }
        }

        public override void Connect(InputFrameSink val)
        {
            base.Connect(val);
            if (Device != null)
            {
                Device.inputFrameSource().connect(val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the RenderCameraController.cs script:**

```cs
//================================================================================================================================
//
//  Copyright (c) 2015-2019 VisionStar Information Technology (Shanghai) Co., Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
//  EasyAR is the registered trademark or trademark of VisionStar Information Technology (Shanghai) Co., Ltd in China
//  and other countries for the augmented reality technology developed by VisionStar Information Technology (Shanghai) Co., Ltd.
//
//================================================================================================================================

using UnityEngine;

namespace easyar
{
    public class RenderCameraController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Camera TargetCamera;
        public RenderCameraParameters ExternalParameters;

        private CameraImageRenderer cameraRenderer;
        private Matrix4x4 currentDisplayCompensation = Matrix4x4.identity;
        private CameraParameters cameraParameters;
        private bool projectHFilp;
        private ARSession arSession;

        protected virtual void OnEnable()
        {
            if (arSession)
            {
                arSession.FrameChange += OnFrameChange;
                arSession.FrameUpdate += OnFrameUpdate;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnDisable()
        {
            if (arSession)
            {
                arSession.FrameChange -= OnFrameChange;
                arSession.FrameUpdate -= OnFrameUpdate;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnDestroy()
        {
            if (cameraParameters != null)
            {
                cameraParameters.Dispose();
            }
            if (ExternalParameters)
            {
                ExternalParameters.Dispose();
            }
        }

        internal void OnAssemble(ARSession session)
        {
            arSession = session;
            if (!TargetCamera)
            {
                TargetCamera = session.Assembly.Camera;
            }
            if (enabled)
            {
                arSession.FrameChange += OnFrameChange;
                arSession.FrameUpdate += OnFrameUpdate;
            }
            cameraRenderer = GetComponent<CameraImageRenderer>();
            if (cameraRenderer)
            {
                cameraRenderer.OnAssemble(session);
            }
        }

        internal void SetProjectHFlip(bool hFlip)
        {
            projectHFilp = hFlip;
        }

        internal void SetRenderImageHFilp(bool hFlip)
        {
            if (cameraRenderer)
            {
                cameraRenderer.SetHFilp(hFlip);
            }
        }

        private void OnFrameChange(OutputFrame outputFrame, Matrix4x4 displayCompensation)
        {
            if (outputFrame == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            currentDisplayCompensation = displayCompensation.inverse;

            using (var frame = outputFrame.inputFrame())
            {
                if (cameraParameters != null)
                {
                    cameraParameters.Dispose();
                }
                cameraParameters = frame.cameraParameters();
                if (ExternalParameters)
                {
                    ExternalParameters.Build(cameraParameters);
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnFrameUpdate(OutputFrame outputFrame)
        {
            var camParameters = ExternalParameters ? ExternalParameters.Parameters : cameraParameters;
            var projection = camParameters.projection(TargetCamera.nearClipPlane, TargetCamera.farClipPlane, TargetCamera.aspect, EasyARController.Instance.Display.Rotation, false, false).ToUnityMatrix();
            if (ExternalParameters)
            {
                projection *= ExternalParameters.Transform;
            }
            projection *= currentDisplayCompensation;
            if (projectHFilp)
            {
                var translateMatrix = Matrix4x4.identity;
                translateMatrix.m00 = -1;
                projection = translateMatrix * projection;
            }
            TargetCamera.projectionMatrix = projection;
            GL.invertCulling = projectHFilp;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting desperate on how to solve the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Has anyone a suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should always include the language tag, in this case the C# tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if anyone is facing the same issue:
to solve the blackscreen simply open "CameraImageRenderer.cs", go to line 180 and replace the line
`commandBuffer.Blit(null, BuiltinRenderTextureType.CameraTarget, material);`
with
`commandBuffer.Blit(material.HasProperty("_MainTex") ? material.GetTexture("_MainTex") : null, BuiltinRenderTextureType.CameraTarget, material);`

This issue got solved in the latest update on EasyAR 4.1. I found the solution here: https://www.easyar.cn/view/questionDetails.html#163

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the solution!